# Can't import a library in CMake

Tags: c++, c, import, cmake, codeblocks

I'm trying to import a static library I made, but this CMake code doesn't work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(C_collections C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_library(C_collections STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(C_collections PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "/Users/alex/Desktop/C_collections.cbp")

add_executable(Main main.c list.h linked_list.h stack.h queue.h dictionary.h)
target_link_libraries(Main GLOBAL C_collections)
```

I still can't `#include` my `C_collections` in `main.c`
How do I fix it?

Comment: IMPORTED_LOCATION should not be a code blocks project file. It should be a folder containing your compiled binary for your library.

Comment: @drescherjm so should that be a ".a" library?

Comment: Also this has nothing to do with `#import`

Comment: Here is the documentation for IMPORTED_LOCATION: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html)

Comment: `#import` is something Microsoft-specific as I recall

Comment: @drescherjm I build an ".a" library, and I used the same code to import it through CMake. How do I use it now if not with #include? (yeah, I made a typo in my post)

Comment: IIRC you need to set the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property on your `IMPORTED` target `C_collections` -- this way when you `target_link_libraries` to it it will automatically set up the required `-I`